# Vercel Deployment Error: "npm run build" exited with 1

Tags: reactjs, deployment, mern, vercel

```
These are logs of deployment detail: 

[15:19:45.948]   throw err;
[15:19:45.948]   ^
[15:19:45.948] 
[15:19:45.948] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[15:19:45.948]   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
[15:19:45.948]   library: 'digital envelope routines',
[15:19:45.948]   reason: 'unsupported',
[15:19:45.948]   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
[15:19:45.948] }
[15:19:45.948] 
[15:19:45.948] Node.js v18.16.1
[15:19:45.972] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Vercel deployment error npm run build exited 1: I already tried adding npm run build in build command and adding enviroment variable CI=false but error remains same`

Comment: Which Webpack version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/15900) on Github. Can you give this a shot?

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
  "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
}
```

Comment: It run the build but server did not verify the login credentials yet